# Ionic v1 Enterprise App No Longer Installs on iOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic-v1

I've got an Ionic v1 app that was built for iOS before Ionic 2 was a thing. I used Xcode to archive the app for Enterprise distribution, so it could be installed on devices for testing. This was all fine and good until some time last week, when we noticed that the app would no longer install on our iOS devices.

What happens now is that you can click the same link in Safari to download the same .ipa file to the same device as it was previously installed on, it will start downloading to the home screen, then when it reaches 100%, the progress wheel disappears but the icon stays dark. Tapping on the icon gives the following error:

`Unable to install "App Name"`
`Please try again later.`

I've tried...

- updating my Ionic CLI to the latest version
- installing the Ionic-v1 toolkit
- updated all of the NPM packages
- run `npm audit fix`
- fixing a few of the Xcode warnings (not they they've ever mattered in the past) about deployment target, icon sizes etc.
- completely removing the iOS platform and re-installing it
- signing using a different team
- letting Xcode automatically manage signing
- ensured I'm building with a Developer profile (not Distribution)

...but haven't managed to find any fixes at all. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what the elusive issue might be?

---

Plugins in use:

- cordova-plugin-camera
- cordova-plugin-compat
- cordova-plugin-console
- cordova-plugin-device
- cordova-plugin-file
- cordova-plugin-file-transfer
- cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
- cordova-plugin-network-information
- cordova-plugin-splashscreen
- cordova-plugin-statusbar
- cordova-plugin-whitelist
- cordova-plugin-x-toast
- cordova-plugin-sqlite-storage
- cordova-plugin-deploy
- cordova-plugin-keyboard
- mx.ferreyra.callnumber

Comment: are you uploading it to itunes and then trying to install?

Comment: @Shoaeb no, I'm just building the app, archiving it as an Enterprise app then uploading the `.ipa` file (plus the manifest and so on) to our server. This has always been fine (and still works for our Ionic 3 apps) but suddenly isn't working for Ionic v1 apps. If I connect the device via USB and run it directly on to the device (ie. not archived, just built then run on the device) then it installs without any issues

Comment: can you post the list of plugina that you are using?

Comment: @Shoaeb updated the question with those :-)

Comment: have you tried removing and adding the platform ios again?

Comment: @Shoaeb yep - sixth thing on the list of things I've tried

Comment: sorry i missed that...
i dont see any other options from the inputs you are providing..

Comment: IMHO this is more of iOS signing issue than of ionic, double check that the provisioning profile is not expired.

Comment: @Joe : Have you checked once enterprise account status? is it valid ? suggested to perform similar checks for provisioning profile and certificates.

Comment: is the mobileprovisioning embed on the ipa the right one ? (rename the .app to .zip, unarchive it; right click on the .app should suggest something like "display the bundle content")

Comment: @Mosbah turns out that it was an expired provisioning profile (not that it gave any kind of indication that that was the problem). If you'd like to post that as an answer, I'll bounty you

Comment: ok will do. happy you solved your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO this is more of iOS signing issue than of ionic, double check that the provisioning profile is not expired.

Comment: This was the cause. I went to the Apple Developer Centre, logged in and reviewed the provision profiles (as well as keys, certificates etc). Created a new provisioning profile, downloaded and installed in Xcode and all was good. Interestingly, this all happened even though I told Xcode to automatically manage signing, so just having that box checked doesn't necessarily stop this happening

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if your UUID device is registered on developer.apple.com and you have to add it to the Provisioning Profile.

If you had all then re-build the app and try it.